# Pure CSS Push/ Slide Menu - Close on Static Button Click

Tags: html, css, slide

I am trying to create a simple, pure CSS push menu. The menu opens and closes when clicking on the Settings icon. This works already. However, I wish to move the icon inside the grey div and have it activate the menu when clicked. At the moment, the settings click only works when the icon is in  the position it currently sits. If I move it inside the div, nothing happens.

Also, I would like to close the menu by clicking on the Settings text or left chevron icon inside the menu. I tried creating a second menu checkbox and associated styles, like so;

```
#menu-toggle-2:checked + .menu-icon {
    right: 30%;
}
```

But doing this only moved the Settings div INSIDE the menu; it did not close the menu itself.

Here is the html code for the page and menu;

```
    <head>
<style>
    .content-container {
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;            
    }        
    
    .slideout-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    right: -28%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 28%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .slideout-sidebar ul {
    list-style: none;
    }
    
    .slideout-sidebar ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D4D7;
    }
    
    #menu-toggle {
    display: none;
    }
    
    .menu-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #menu-toggle:checked ~ .slideout-sidebar {
    right: 0px;
    }
    
    #menu-toggle:checked + .menu-icon {
    right: 30%;
    }
    
    #menu-toggle:checked ~ .content-container {
    padding-right: 28%;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Body;

```
    <body>
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
<label for="menu-toggle" class="menu-icon">
<img class="icon" src="images2/ic-of-settings-gy.svg" style="width:33px;height:33px;" />
</label>    
<div id="divMenu" class="slideout-sidebar">
<ul>
<li>
<img class="icon" src="images2/ic-of-chevron-left-gy.svg" />
<span style="padding-left:10px">Settings</span>                
</li>
<li>
About
</li>
<li>
Contact
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
<div class="container">
<div style="width:780px;height:800px;background-color:grey;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is the image of the Settings menu item, which I would like to close the menu when clicked;

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, if anyone needs the info. The trick is to stick a hidden input on the page, and a second one in your desired location, with the same ID. Code below.

```
<style>
    #menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu-icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.25rem;
        right: 1.25rem;
        z-index: 2;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    content {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    nav {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        width: 28%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 -28% 0 0;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    }

    nav ul {
        height: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    nav li {
        padding: 1.125rem 0 1.125rem 0;
        border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid rgba(209, 212, 215, 1);
    }

    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        z-index: 500;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ nav {
        margin: 0;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ content {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-28%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-28%, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(-28%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-28%, 0, 0);
    }
</style>

<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="font-weight-bold settings-list-item">
            <label for="menu-toggle" class="list-spacer">
                <img src="images/chevron-left.png" />
                <span><b class="ng-tns-c1354-3 font-15 padding-left-20">Settings</b></span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="font-weight-bold settings-list-item">
            Home
        </li>
        <li class="list-spacer">
            About
        </li>
        <li class="list-spacer">
            Contact
        </li>           
    </ul>
</nav>  
<content>
    <div style="width:780px;height:800px;background-color:grey;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
        <label for="menu-toggle" class="nav-icon margin-top-35">
            <img class="settings-icon" src="images/settings.png" />
        </label>
    </div>
</content>
```